# HTML onchange attribute not working for select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I have a couple select elements with `onchange` attributes that fire a different functions. For some reason, the function is not running through. I think the problem is in the `onchange` attribute. Here is the HTML:

```
<select id="select_level" onchange="updateJumpLevelLink(this.SelectedIndex.value)">
    <option value="easy">Level</option>
    <option value="easy">Easy</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="hard">Hard</option>
</select>
<select id="select_puzzle" onchange="updateJumpPuzzleLink(this.SelectedIndex.value)">
    <option value="1">Puzzle</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<a href="sudoku?level=easy&puzzle=1" id="jump_link"><div id="jump">Jump</div></a>
```

This is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        $('#select_puzzle').append('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
    }
    function updateJumpLevelLink(new_value) {
        var current_link = $('#jump_link').attr('href');
        $('#jump_link').attr('href', 'sudoku?level='+new_value+'&puzzle='+current_link.substr(current_link.indexOf('?')).split('&')[1].substr('puzzle='.length));
    }
    function updateJumpPuzzleLink(new_value) {
        var current_link = $('#jump_link').attr('href');
        $('#jump_link').attr('href', 'sudoku?level='+current_link.substr(current_link.indexOf('?')).split('&')[0].substr('level='.length)+'&puzzle='+new_value);
    }
});
```

Let me know if you see the problem here. Thanks.

Comment: can you post /share a fiddle for this? using static values first

Comment: @ejay_francisco: I update my post and here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yBe6J/)

Comment: `Let me know if you see the problem here` You have two function declarations (*updateJumpLevelLink* and *updateJumpPuzzleLink*) inside a function. The functions are not called, nor assigned to an outer variable and are no longer callable once the enclosing function has finished executing. Therefore they can't be called by the listener.

Comment: @RobG as I addressed in my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that your functions are defined in the document ready, so it won't work because the functions technically don't exist on the global scale. You need to move it outside the document.ready().

Your second problem is that you're passing the wrong value. "this.SelectedIndex.value" should be "this.Value", otherwise it doesn't send anything into the function.

```
<select id="select_level" onchange="updateJumpLevelLink(this.value)">
```

Here's the fix: http://jsfiddle.net/yBe6J/3/

Answer (score 2):

i dont know what you want to do in your project, but if the case is onchange, i think this will help you, add jQuery in your JS Libraries it will help you a lot here is my example onCHange sample using jQuery

```
$( "#select_level" ).change(function() {
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Where `$(this).val()` is just an extremely inefficient way of writing `this.value`.

Comment: maybe yes but i just want to explain and to show how jQuery use its function and commands, no offense :)

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w67tg/1/) full working.

i used

```
$( "#select_level" ).change(function() {
  var current_link = $('#jump_link').attr('href');
        $('#jump_link').attr('href', 'sudoku?level='+$(this).val()+'&puzzle='+current_link.substr(current_link.indexOf('?')).split('&')[1].substr('puzzle='.length));
});
$( "#select_puzzle" ).change(function() {
 var current_link = $('#jump_link').attr('href');
        $('#jump_link').attr('href', 'sudoku?level='+current_link.substr(current_link.indexOf('?')).split('&')[0].substr('level='.length)+'&puzzle='+$(this).val());
});
```